Should Buddhists support Louisiana mandating Christian morality commandments in schools?
A bill signed into law this week makes Louisiana the only state to require that the Ten Commandments be displayed in every classroom, in public schools and colleges because they claim there is no separation of church and state as popularly claimed.
Would the Buddha be against reminding children about wholesome morals even if they were Christian interpretations?  Would the Buddha be against reminding children about wholesome morals given in a Buddhist context? Why? Why not?

What is the definition of wholesome and moral?

The definition of wholesome and moral are habits and beliefs that lead one away from suffering and towards wholesome wellbeing as opposed to sensual wellbeing , like in the 10 commandments. I don't see how that is a matter of opinion. If one thinks killing & stealing doesn't lead to suffering then one has problems. There are many ways of accessing anatta like humility from not taking a spiritual leaders name in vain.

Your definition is pragmatic and rational; in line I think with what most Buddhists believe. In our modern society, we need to go beyond a prescriptive definition of wholesomeness and morality. One that can be proven with research and validated with empirical data. Wholesomeness and morals are no longer the sole prerogative of any religion.


I know that people say they are, but I don't think of the 10 commandments as "Christian" -- they're old testament, and not what Christ answered when He was asked.

I'm not sure about the First commandment

There is surely some way for people to interpret it "well"
There may be other, more evil ways for people to interpret it

So far as I know, America was founded to have no "established" religion -- unlike in the UK! -- at around that time there were religious wars and persecution.

I don't think it (i.e. "the 10 commandments") explains the reason for morality very well -- which at best might make it an article of blind faith, and worst counter-productive, for example:


The shalt not kill.
Why not?
Because God said not to.
But I don't believe in God -- evidently doesn't exist -- so I've no reason to conform to your conventional morality.


It also leads to fallacies like:


If you don't believe in God, then you must be immoral


And:


If there's immorality in society, then the solution is "more religion".



I'm not sure it's age-appropriate, for any age -- too far out for young children, too simplistic for older ones -- maybe children should be learning "morality", even if not "religion", in pre-school. Possibly that -- providing and improving pre-schools, training "early childhood education" workers -- might be more wholesome or something.



It seems like this answer isn't based on Buddhist doctrine and practice. I suppose I assumed it goes without saying, that Buddhist doctrine is careful to explain "why?" in considerable detail.

It also warns against "sectarian" arguments like, "Only this is true, all other views are false" -- which help to explain why I might mistrust teaching the first commandment, and is sort of why I started to learn about other "views", including Buddhism.

Sometimes, I can’t help but feel/share parents’ angst over modern/liberal attitude within society and the resulting violence, drugs, sex and sheer self-centeredness that afflicted it. Perhaps, this is a genuine response by concerned groups just trying to create what they think is an answer....although in my mind, a misguided one.

there is also a good chance it backfires, so many disgruntled kids with access to guns..

if u read the first commandment, '...have no other gods before me' - subconsciously, how is this interpreted? who is me?

@blue_ego Are you saying that, "subconsciously", the "me" might be  be interpreted as "self-referential"? Because I might associate that experience with paranoia -- not a happy experience -- possibly "delusions of grandeur" also, equating "me" with "God". In contrast to that there is (less "extreme") Buddhist doctrine about "identity-view", and about relating with "other people".

I think a clear-headed buddhist should have an eye on karma here. This kind of legal mandate suggests a whole lot about those imposing it:

These people have lost faith that others will act according to religion tenets (i.e., be good, reasonable, and do the 'right' thing)
These people have lost faith in their ability to convince others to act according to religion tenets
This loss of faith in others, and in their own power to convince others, generates misery: they are forced into a corner where they must:

question or qualify their religion, creating misery for themselves, or…
impose the religion on others through force and fear, creating misery for others



So what do Buddhists do when we see people trapped in dukkha and tanhā? First and foremost we find compassion, for all sides. Laws are impermanent; they come and go, reflecting the miseries of the world around them. We can accept the mandate (knowing it will pass) or oppose it (helping it to pass); we can work to ease the differential sufferings of those who suffer under the mandate or of those who suffer to impose the mandate. It's just a matter of seeing the suffering and seeking an end to it, an effort that leaves no suffering in its wake.

Ask any religious person on what is moral or wholesome. More often than not we get very opinionated ideas regardless of the faith, be it Hinduism, Christianity, Catholicism, Buddhism, Islam or otherwise. The problem comes when the religious extremists within such faiths tried to impose their morality on the rest who don’t share their beliefs.
Would the Buddha ever impose his teachings on anyone? I don’t believe he would ever do such a thing. No matter how wholesome, moral and virtuous the Dharma is, the Buddha encouraged the listener to know for themselves before deciding. In the Kalama sutta, it was taught:

don’t go by reports, by legends, by traditions, by scripture, by logical conjecture, by inference, by analogies, by agreement through pondering views, by probability, or by the thought

The central thrust in this sutra is when you know for yourselves which is totally in line with the scientific method that relied on validation and verification to establish true knowledge. This also brings us to the importance of secularism and its emphasis on the naturalistic approach in managing human affairs whether it is in the classroom, office or the world.
While secularism had been accused of leading to hedonism and debauchery, we often forget its importance in promoting a common space for people of different religious faiths and whatever beliefs to come together and chart an acceptable course for the majority and the future. There is no other alternative to secularism that I can think of that can achieve this! It is for this very reason that we must keep the schools, workplace and public sphere/discourses secular. The moment secularism is gone and replaced by a religious/fundamentalist/extremist way of doing things, problems and issues that do not accord with this way would be ignored, suppressed and crushed. There are so many such instances in history and the resulting sufferings that arose due to such oppression.
The leading criticism that the secular approach is hedonistic and leads to moral decay ignored the works by researchers into areas like stealing, adultery, various studies on guns and violence and other social issues. The findings from such research inform, clarify and steer public policies albeit with the usual political lobbying and vested interests. Perhaps, a better job could be done to disseminate such findings to the public to boost their confidence and acceptance that secularism works even in areas traditionally monopolized by religion such as morality and ethics.
Thus, I think Buddhists, in general, should support a secular approach in teaching morality in schools. Doing so is all about protecting ourselves, others and our collective future from extremism.

The Ten Commandments appear not Christian teachings and are certainly not universal teachings. They appear to be tribal teachings of a tribal religion. For example, the first and second commandment (below) do not apply to all people:

I am the Lord your God, who brought you out of Egypt, out of the land
of slavery. You shall have no other gods before me.
You shall not make for yourself an image in the form of anything in
heaven above or on the earth beneath or in the waters below. You shall
not bow down to them or worship them.
Exodus 20

The Ten Commandments oppose Buddhism, traditional Christianity & other religions.
When Jesus of Christianity later referred to the commandments, he only referred to six commandments:

Jesus replied. “If you want to enter life, keep the commandments.”
“Which ones?”.
Jesus replied, “‘You shall not murder, you shall not commit adultery,
you shall not steal, you shall not give false testimony, honor your
father and mother,’ and ‘love your neighbor as yourself.
Matthew 19

In addition, the meaning of "You shall not murder" and "You shall not covet your neighbor’s neighbor’s house or land" is not clear because these commandments are found in Deuteronomy 5 yet in Deuteronomy 7 the commandment is made to genocide the tribes of Canaan (Palestine). Here, the impression is the commandment to not murder only applies to not murdering members of the tribe.
In short, the Ten Commandments appear to be tribal rules relating only to how to act towards members of that tribe. They appear to have no universal application.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
